# How do I adjust the spacing between buttons in a Layout such as the HorizontalLayout in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

For example how do I reduce the spacing between the buttons in the following HorizontalLayout:

[image]

The code:

```
HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
horizontalLayout.setWidthFull();
horizontalLayout.setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.END);
buttons.forEach(button -> {
    horizontalLayout.add(button);
    horizontalLayout.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_SMALL);
});
```

** This is for Vaadin Flow (Vaadin 14+)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of the default "spacing" theme on the HL, use "spacing-s" or "spacing-xs"

```java
var hl = new HorizontalLayout();
hl.setSpacing(false);
hl.getThemeList().add("spacing-s");
```

see [JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.7.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/orderedlayout/HorizontalLayout.html#setSpacing-boolean-)